# Referencing Excel VBA functions associated with Chart sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have this function associated with an EXCEL chart sheet

```
Public Sub SetAxisLimits()
```

The name of the chart sheet is `Chart1` but is referred to in the VBA window as `Chart2` (see below)

[image]

If I call it using

```
Call Chart2.SetAxisLimits
```

or

```
Call Charts("Chart1").SetAxisLimits
```

then everything is OK.  However, if I try this:

```
Dim xlCht as Chart
Set xlCht = Charts("Chart1")
Call xlCht.SetAxisLimits
```

Then I get the following EXCEL VBA error `Method or data member not found`. I'm a little confused about this - could anyone please explain what is going on?  Thanks!!

Comment: FWIW a document module with "Chart2" `(Name)` property and a "Chart1" `Name` looks like a disaster in the making ;-)

Comment: That's EXCEL for you!  This is just an example to illustrate the problem but I take your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can change the name of the object in the VB project to "Chart1" or the name of the chart sheet to "Chart2", so the names line up.

Second, it sounds like the sub is in the code module associated with the chart. You probably want to put it in a regular code module, and rewrite it to pass in a chart, then apply the actions to this chart:

```
Public Sub SetAxisLimits(TheChart As Chart)
    With TheChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        ' etc.
    End With
End Sub
```

Call it like this:

```
SetAxisLimits ActiveChart
SetAxisLimits ActiveWorkbook.Charts(1)
SetAxisLimits ActiveWorkbook.Charts("Chart1")
```

Comment: Hi Jon the sub is indeed in the chart's code module.  Have put it into a separate code module as you suggested and everything seems fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the realm of classes and interfaces!

`Chart1` *is a* `Chart`, like `Sheet1` *is a* `Worksheet` - all are *classes* / object types, and all classes expose a *default interface* - in the case of `Chart1`, the *default interface* exposes the members inherited from the base `Chart` class, *and* the custom `Public` members implemented in that chart module's code-behind.

So when the compiler sees this:

```
Dim c As Chart2
Set c = Chart2
c.DoSomething 'works
```

Ignoring the fact that such a declaration is entirely redundant (`Chart2` is already readily usable everywhere in the project), it sees `c` through the lens of the `Chart2` interface. If the `Chart2` module has a `DoSomething` public procedure, then `c.DoSomething` can be bound at compile-time, and it works.

But when you do this:

```
Dim c As Chart
Set c = Chart2
c.DoSomething 'fails
```

Now the compiler sees `c` through the lens of the `Chart` interface: it doesn't matter that `Chart2` has a `DoSomething` method anymore, because while we're looking at the very same object as before, we're no longer using its default interface (i.e. `Chart2`), and because `Chart` defines no `DoSomething` member, this code cannot be bound at compile-time, and it fails because the *method or member is not found*.

Now consider this:

```
Dim c As Object 'or Variant
Set c = Chart2
c.DoSomething 'works, but no member list after typing the . dot
c.DoSmoehting 'compiles, but fails to run
```

This time, the compiler sees `c` as some `IDispatch` object (`IUnknown` given a `Variant`), and any member calls made against it is no longer resolved at compile-time: this is *late binding* now, and if the member isn't found at run-time you get error 438 - the run-time equivalent of the compile error you are asking about. You get no autocompletion, no intellisense, no compile-time validation, and `Option Explicit` won't save you from a typo.

Comment: Hi Mathieu - thanks for your reply.  But I'm still confused ...  I am not declaring `xlCht` as a member of the `'Chart2` class - I am using the built in XL `Chart` class.  I don't understand why `Charts("Chart1").SetAxisLimits` works and `xlCht.SetAxisLimits` doesn't.  Are you suggesting it is a result of early vs late binding?

Comment: @PetGriffin yes. `Charts("Chart1")` returns an `Object`, but if `xlCht` is declared with a data type, you can only invoke the members that exist on the declared type's interface. So `As Chart2` works because that's where `SetAxisLimits` is defined, but `As Chart` doesn't, because it doesn't know anything about `SetAxisLimits`. Unless the declared type's interface is *extensible*, you can only legally invoke members that exist on that type. `Object` OTOH, lets you call anything whether it exists or not.